# Is it possible to deploy Lightning Experience email templates (Integrated Email) from org to org?

Tags: deployment, email-template

I have created some email templates using Integrated Email in the new Lightning Experience. I would like to deploy these to another org. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please refer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251031/lightning-email-templates-deployment

Answer (score 1):

As of Winter '17 this is not possible. You can download email templates created in Lightning Experience, but if you attempt to deploy these to other orgs using the metadata API they are created as Classic email templates, which are incompatible with the Lightning Experience email templates. 
On the backend there are 2 fields in the database that are used to distinguish Classic email templates from LEX templates: EntityType and UiType. But those 2 fields are read-only even for SysAdmins, so they can't be modified once the entity is deployed. Theoretically it might be possible to [create email templates using the REST or SOAP API, following these instructions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm?search_text=emailtemplate), but it's not possible using the Metadata API.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Email Templates are now records of the EmailTemplate sobject, which means that you can migrate them using Data Loader.

I am not sure if that's something new but it works in Winter'18 - just remember to select the 'Show all Salesforce objects' checkbox when selecting the sobject.